# write one's own little ftp server

Tags: java, ftp

I'd like to code an ftp server in java, just for practice. What I would need to do is have a client send the ftp commands and then "parse" those commands on the server and translate them to file system access, right? I don't want anything fancy, just implement some basic commands.

So when the client sends "cd directoryname" I check the substrings before and after the space and then get a list of the files from the specified directory. Something along those lines, right?

I looked a bit at this source code here: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/mina/asyncweb/trunk/server/src/main/java/org/apache/asyncweb/server/ but couldn’t find any< code that reads in the ftp commands...

Am I going in the right direction with this or am I completely off?

Comment: I'd say you're completely off. You're talking about a simple server and saying a lot of "I'd like to", which makes it seem that you don't really know what you're trying to do. To top it off, you're looking at the sources for Apache Mina, which is definitely not related to "simple FTP server". Do you know how to work with Sockets?

Comment: yepp, I do indeed :)

Comment: Then read up on the FTP protocol and test your server with an existing FTP client. Shouldn't be hard to implement a few of the basic commands at first, since it's similar to creating an echo server. If you've created a client-server program using sockets before, there shouldn't be problems.

Comment: yeah, that's what I thought, as well: the ftp commands are there and I can just send them over the sockets and then receive the server response over the sockets... I just wanted to make sure I'm not going about this completely wrong. Thanks!!